# Button onClick event triggering two times in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend, react-hook-form

I have an object which is a store for the list of groups and list of inputs for each of group.
The number of inputs may be changed if I click on "Add new name" or "Remove".
The problem is when I click "Remove" button on some input the onClick handler triggering two times for some reason and because of that two inputs removes instead of one.

Here is the code of my component:

```
    import { Listbox, Transition } from "@headlessui/react";
        import {
          CheckIcon,
          ChevronUpDownIcon,
          EllipsisVerticalIcon,
        } from "@heroicons/react/24/solid";
        import classNames from "classnames";
        import React, {Fragment, useEffect, useRef, useState} from "react";
        import { useDrag, useDrop, XYCoord } from "react-dnd";
        import {
          Controller,
          FieldArrayWithId,
          useFormState,
          useWatch,
        } from "react-hook-form";
        import Trash from "../../../../components/icons/trash";
        import RangeCombobox from "../../../../components/rangeCombobox";
        import SlideOver from "../../../../components/side-popup";
        import {PlusCircleIcon} from "@heroicons/react/24/outline";
    
        const ManageRaceItem: React.FC<
          ManageRaceItemProps
        > = ({
          index,
          field,
          checkNames,
          errorsArr,
          handleErrors,
          manageChartState,
          candidatesNamesChecked
        }) => {
          const {
            moveRace,
            removeRace,
            form: { control, register, unregister, watch, getValues },
          } = manageChartState;
        
          const [dRaceName, setDRaceName] = useState("");
          const { errors } = useFormState({ control, name: "races" });
          const races = useWatch({ control, name: "races" });
          const participants = useWatch({ control, name: "participants" });
        
          const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
          const [{ handlerId }, drop] = useDrop({
            accept: "CHART-RACE",
            collect(monitor) {
              return { handlerId: monitor.getHandlerId() };
            },
            hover(item: any, monitor) {
              if (!ref.current) return;
              const dragIndex = item.index;
              const hoverIndex = index;
              if (dragIndex === hoverIndex) return;
              const hoverBoundingRect = ref.current?.getBoundingClientRect();
              const hoverMiddleY =
                (hoverBoundingRect.bottom - hoverBoundingRect.top) / 2;
              const clientOffset = monitor.getClientOffset();
              const hoverClientY = (clientOffset as XYCoord).y - hoverBoundingRect.top;
              if (dragIndex < hoverIndex && hoverClientY < hoverMiddleY) return;
              if (dragIndex > hoverIndex && hoverClientY > hoverMiddleY) return;
              moveRace(dragIndex, hoverIndex);
              item.index = hoverIndex;
            },
          });
        
          const [, drag] = useDrag(() => ({
            type: "CHART-RACE",
            item: () => {
              return { id: field.id, index };
            },
            collect: () => ({}),
          }));
        
          drag(drop(ref));
        
          const getCountAllFields = (obj: object) => {
            let sum = 0;
            for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
              if (typeof value === 'number') {
                sum = sum + value;
              } else {
                if(typeof value[0] === 'number') {
                  sum = sum + value.reduce((partialSum: number, a: number) => partialSum + a, 0);
                } else {
                  sum = sum + value.length;
                }
              }
            }
            return sum;
          }
        
          const [isHeadlessOpen, setIsHeadlessOpen] = useState(false);
          const [inputs, setInputs] = useState<{[key: string]: any}>({});
          const [filledInputs, setFilledInputs] = useState<{[key: string]: any}>({});
          const [pCandidates, setPCandidates] = useState<{[key: string]: number}>({});
        
          useEffect(() => {
            [{name: 'Candidates'}].forEach((group, idx) => {
              if(pCandidates[group.name] || pCandidates[group.name] === 0) {
                  const fields = Array.from({length: pCandidates[group.name]}, (_, i) => i + 1).map((item, i) => {
                      return (
                          <div key={`name-${i}`} className="flex">
                              <input
                                  {...register(`races.${index}.candidateNames.${i}.name`)}
                                  type="text"
                                  placeholder="Full name"
                                  className={classNames("w-full py-3 mb-2 px-4 bg-[#E6EBF5] rounded-md", {
                                    "outline outline-2 outline-red-500 focus:outline-red-500":
                                      errors?.races?.[index]?.name,
                                  })}
                                  onBlur={(e) => {
                                    setFilledInputs(prev => {
                                      let obj = {...prev, [group.name]: prev[group.name] ? prev[group.name] : []}
                                      let arr = obj[group.name];
                                      arr[i] = e.target.value.length > 0 ? 1 : 0;
                                      return {...obj, [group.name]: arr}
                                    })
                                  }}
                              />
                              <input
                                  {...register(`races.${index}.candidateNames.${i}.order`)}
                                  type="number"
                                  value={Number(i)}
                                  style={{display: 'none'}}
                              />
                              <div className="ml-2">
                                  <button
                                    className="p-2 mt-2 bg-gray-200 rounded-full"
    ///////////////////////////////  Here is the problem, onClick handler triggering two times
                                    onClick={() => {
                                      setInputs((prev) => {
                                            console.log('I am called two times');
                                            unregister(`races.${index}.candidateNames.${i}.name`)
                                            unregister(`races.${index}.candidateNames.${i}.order`)
                                            prev[group.name].splice(i, 1)
                                            return {...prev }
                                          }
                                      )
                                    }}
                                  >
                                    <Trash className="w-4 h-4" />
                                  </button>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          )
                      })
        
                setInputs(prev => {
                  return {...prev, [group.name]: fields}
                })
              }
            })
          }, [pCandidates])

return (
    <>
    <div
      ref={ref}
      data-handler-id={handlerId}
      className="relative flex w-full p-5 mb-8 bg-white rounded-md shadow-md flex-col"
    >
...
...
...
    <SlideOver
      open={isHeadlessOpen}
      setOpen={setIsHeadlessOpen}
      title="Edit Candidate Names"
      subtitle={`${getValues()?.races[index]?.name} Race`}
    >
      <div className="flex flex-col border-gray-300">
          {
            [{name: 'Candidates'}].map((group, idx) => {
              if(pCandidates[group.name]) {
                return (
                  <>
                    <div style={{marginBottom: '20px'}}>
                      <span style={{marginRight: '10px'}}>{group.name.toUpperCase()}</span>
                      <span>{`(${getCountAllFields(filledInputs?.[group.name] ?? 0)}/${pCandidates[group.name]})`}</span>
                      <div className="flex flex-col w-[380px]">
                        {inputs[group.name]}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <button
                      onClick={() => {
                        setPCandidates((prev) => ({...prev, [group.name]: prev[group.name] + 1}));
                      }}
                      type="button"
                      className={classNames(
                        "w-auto font-semibold py-2 flex justify-start items-center -mt-6 mb-8 text-primary-blue rounded-md"
                      )}
                    >
                      <PlusCircleIcon className="w-6 mr-2" />
                      Add Another Candidate
                    </button>
                  </>
                )
              }
            })
          }
      </div>
    </SlideOver>
    </div>
    </>
);
};

export default ManageRaceItem;
```

Comment: Hi Dmitry, your useEffect creates a React anti-pattern. The useEffect hook is creating new components (the fields array) every time pCandidates state changes, and then it updates the inputs state with these newly created components. This is considered an anti-pattern because it's generally not good practice to store components in state. Instead, it would be better to store just the data in state and use this data to render your components directly in the JSX return.

Comment: One potential issue might be a re-render of the component. When React components re-render due to state or props changes, the event handlers are re-created.

In your useEffect, you are updating the state setInputs. If this leads to a re-render, it might cause a second call to your onClick handler, especially if the event is not finished processing before the re-render.

You could potentially use useCallback hook to memorize your onClick function and prevent it from being re-created on each render.